# Is there a way to link an SQL database to an LDAP server

Tags: sql, ldap

We have an SQL contacts database that links into all our project information with lots and bells and whistles.

It has recently been suggested that we make the contacts part of this information available to our end users in their email clients - so we are looking at setting up an LDAP server

Are there any out there that will allow us to map the information in the DB (probably a view I'd suspect) to an LDAP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLDAP has [support for a metadata driven SQL backend](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/978.html) using [back-sql](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html). The [state of testing varies with your chosen RDBMS backend](http://lists.arthurdejong.org/openldap-software/2005/07/msg00087.html).

Answer (score 1):

UnboundID's [Synchronization Server](http://www.unboundid.com/products/synchronization-server.php) supports synchronizing databases with directory servers in real-time and in bulk.