# How to populate an organisational unit with users from an external database in apacheDS

Tags: authentication, ldap, apacheds

I'm trying to setup LDAP so that it authenticates users against an external database using ApacheDS.
I've already managed to setup an organisational unit ou=users, but unfortunately I was only able to add users manually so far.
Although I tried to find a solution on the web, I haven't found much, which I think indicates that I'm missing the right wording to search for a solution.

PS Since I'm pretty new to LDAP it would also be nice to get some tips about good books and tutorials.

Comment: haven't found a way to integrate an external user database into LDAP.
I'm starting to think that this is not the way ldap is meant to work.

Comment: Ok gonna checkout openldap. They seem to offer a possibillity to link a rdbms using back-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677131/is-there-a-way-to-link-an-sql-database-to-an-ldap-server/7719093#7719093.
Does apacheds offer a similar feature?

Comment: Ok openldap not an option anymore, but I had a little breaktrough regarding apacheDS. The ideal way seems to be to write a **custom partition**. Will post an answer as soon as I have finished coding. If you think I'm on the wrong track don't hesitate commenting :)

Comment: So after a little irc chat with the apacheDS guys I found out that  as suspected the way to go would be to implement a **custom partition**.
According to them this not so easy and may take some time to implement.
They said that they will try to upload a sample partition implementation this weekend, that i can use as a starting point.
Since basically i just want to do some authentication an alternative could be, to write an authenticator that delegates the authentication to the DB (Should take about 2 days according to elecarny). will try to do that as a first step.

Comment: I know that was a long time ago, but did you manage to sync apacheDS with external database? I'm struggling with same thing now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called LSC-project that they claim to be able to sync data.
http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/latest/sample

> LSC is an Open source connector to synchronize identities between an
>   LDAP directory and any data source, including any database with a JDBC
>   connector, another LDAP server, flat files, REST API …

I'm trying to sync my postgresql with an ApacheDS. Will get back to this if it works (if I don't forget).